# Use XSLT to transform a child node but leave the rest intact

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML where I only want to modify a specific section, and leave the rest intact, how can this be done? i.e I only want to modify the node AA2

```
<root>
  <parentHeader>
  </parentHeader>
  <body>
    <ChildAA>
      <AA1>
        <foo>bar</foo>
        <foo>bar2</foo>    
      </AA1>
      <AA2>
        <foo>bar</foo>
        <foo>bar2</foo>    
      </AA2>
     </ChildAA>
     <ChildBB>
      <BB1>
       <foo>bar</foo>
       <foo>bar2</foo>
      </BB1> 
      <BB2>
       <foo>bar</foo>
       <foo>bar2</foo>
      </BB2>   
     </ChildBB>
   </body>
</root>
```

I have the following XSLT which only returns the modified section. How can I include everything else?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
     <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

      <!-- Whenever you match any node or any attribute -->
      <xsl:template match="/*"> 
           <xsl:apply-templates/>  
      </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="AA2">
       <RenamedAA2>    
         <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </RenamedAA2>
    </xsl:template>    
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am looking for something like this as result

```
<root>
  <parentHeader>
  </parentHeader>
  <body>
    <ChildAA>
      <AA1>
        <foo>bar</foo>
        <foo>bar2</foo>    
      </AA1>
     <RenamedAA2>
        <foo>bar</foo>
      </RenamedAA2>
      <RenamedAA2>
        <foo>bar2</foo>    
      </RenamedAA2>
     </ChildAA>
     <ChildBB>
      <BB1>
       <foo>bar</foo>
       <foo>bar2</foo>
      </BB1> 
      <BB2>
       <foo>bar</foo>
       <foo>bar2</foo>
      </BB2>   
     </ChildBB>
   </body>
</root>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want is the [identity transform](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying).

Your template that has the comment `Whenever you match any node or any attribute` isn't doing what you think. It's only matching the root element.

Also, you're stripping all `text()` nodes with that last template.

Here's an example of what you should do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!--Identity Transform.-->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="AA2/foo">
        <RenamedAA2>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </RenamedAA2>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="AA2">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<root>
   <parentHeader/>
   <body>
      <ChildAA>
         <AA1>
            <foo>bar</foo>
            <foo>bar2</foo>
         </AA1>
         <RenamedAA2>
            <foo>bar</foo>
         </RenamedAA2>
         <RenamedAA2>
            <foo>bar2</foo>
         </RenamedAA2>
      </ChildAA>
      <ChildBB>
         <BB1>
            <foo>bar</foo>
            <foo>bar2</foo>
         </BB1>
         <BB2>
            <foo>bar</foo>
            <foo>bar2</foo>
         </BB2>
      </ChildBB>
   </body>
</root>
```